# List ItemRenderer duplicated when Sorting List's dataprovider

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

The title basically tells my problem. I am sorting the dataProvider for a list. I have itemRenderers on the list. 3 items get built, opt1, opt2, opt3 - I then have a drag and drop on the list and when that is finished I wait for my custom newRank variable to be set in the dataProvider of the list. then after sorting the list, my item renderer renders out 5 items, not 3: opt2, opt3, opt1 (first three are sorted properly), opt3, opt3. 
I have tried to sort with a basic sort and a customFunction and I cannot get it to sort properly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public function sortItemsByNewRank():void{
    var srt:Sort = new Sort();
    //srt.fields = [new SortField("newRank", true, false, true)];
    srt.compareFunction = myCompare;
    var ac:ArrayCollection = this.dataProvider as ArrayCollection;
    ac.sort = srt;
    ac.refresh();
}
private function myCompare(a:Object, b:Object, fields:Array = null):int {
    LOG.debug("ExtendedList a and b: "+a.newRank+"     "+b.newRank);
    if(a.newRank == b.newRank) {
        return 0;
    } else if(a.newRank > b.newRank) {
        return 1;
    } else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the sort is actually working. What isn't working is the List component drawing the dataProvider after refresh. It is duplicating items, I tried calling invalidateDisplayList and invalidateList to get the list to redraw itself, but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Take one [Bindable] variable and give it to your list...
And in sorting function use that variable and call refresh...
eg.

```
[Bindable]
private var _dataProvider:ArrayCollection

public function sortItemsByNewRank():void{
    var srt:Sort = new Sort();
    //srt.fields = [new SortField("newRank", true, false, true)];
    srt.compareFunction = myCompare;
    _dataProvider.sort = srt;
    _dataProvider.refresh();
}

<s:List dataProvider="{_dataProvider}"/>
```

May be this will solve your duplicate problem.....

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. Most of the issue had to do with the DATA_CHANGE event firing over and over while my sort was running. I put a flag in and it fixed my issue. A little hacky, but the invalidateList allowed me to clear and reinitialize the data into the UI.